# ASP.NET MVC Model Data Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to bind data to a class member? Here is an example

```
public class A
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public A a {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Class B)
{

}
```

Now I want create an class B object in a View page, the posted data comes from this page is below:
     ID = 1
     Description = "Description B"
     A = 1

I want to all the above data is able to automatically filled into an instance B and the MVC is able to fill 
the ID of class B, the description of class B, but is not able to fill data into the class A which is a member of Class B.

Actually All I want is when the posted data A = 1, then the MVC can be create an new instance of class A for class B, and set the ID values of class A to 1.

I know there might be put some attributes on class A, and it will tell MVC do some mappings based on the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can a value of `1` be bound to a complex property of type `A`? It's got nothing to do with *some attributes on class A*! You need to construct your html correctly so it can be bound

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  B model = new B();
  return View(model)
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(B model)
{

}
```

View

```
@model B
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.a.ID) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.a.Description)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```